# browse debug history in VSCode

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

How can I browse the debug history in VSCode?

In *pycharm* there is a `Browse history` [bottom](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debug-tool-window-console.html#context-menu-commands), where you can view the debug console entries.
The typical situation is that during a debug session I want to copy from the command history a few commands into my source code, and for that, I'm looking for a convenient way to explore the debug command history.

I know I can navigate the command history through the up/down arrows, but this became tedious when you want to briefly explore your history and selectively copy some of your previous commands.

Comment: There is a similar [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/158470) in GitHub. You can vote for it and supplement it

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to copy-paste, not the _inputs_ arguments but rather the command executed through the  _debug_console_

Comment: You can add comments below, or open a new issue to discuss this new function